# Jquery is(":empty) not working after .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After clicking on a button which sends a form using Ajax, it is suppose to fade out a div and remove it from the page. The fade out and remove works fine as I checked in the browser that the HTML gets removed and it does, however the if statement which checks if the div is empty does not work for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
$(".sessionSignOutBtn").submit(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();

    newAjaxRequest($(this).serialize(), "index.php?ajax=sessionSignOut", removedSessionBox);

    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut("slow", function()
    {
      $(this).remove();
    });

    if($("#otherSessions").is(':empty'))
    {
      $("#otherSessionsTitle").text("No other active sessions");
    }
  });
```

The if statement for #otherSessions is what does not get executed, I checked the div id and they match up, if I render the page with no content in #otherSessions the if statement works, its only when I use in within my submit listener.

The newAjaxRequest is there to just fire off an ajax request nothing else.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Just a guess but what does `$(this).parent().parent()` reference to? Maybe you remove `#otherSessions` beforehand?

Comment: @zusatzstoff because the form submit button is within its own div so to remove the div where the form is located I used them, it does atually remove all the content (html) from #otherSessions as I checked in the browser it basically becomes `<div id="#otherSessions"></div>`

Comment: You do realize that `fadeOut()` starts a non-blocking animation, meaning the rest of your code is still running while the animation happens. So your check is executed during the time before the `remove()` call is called. Try moving the check within the `fadeOut` callback.

Comment: @Erdss4 I'm very sure `$(this).remove();` does not refer to `".sessionSignOutBtn"` it refers to its grand parent. Maybe you can try it without the dom removal for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to check whether a `div` has `children` or not, use `if( $("#otherSessions").children().length === 0 )`.

Comment: Thank you, I used part of your answer to help me, not sure why someone down voted you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Denialos and Patrick Evans I sorted out out.

Because of fadeOut being non blocking I added the if statement within the complete function and used Denialos's answer to check if my div has any children because just using `if($("#otherSessions").is(':empty'))` did work because `remove()` was leaving white space.

So my final fix looks like:

```
$(this).parent().parent().fadeOut("slow", function()
    {
      $(this).remove();

      if($("#otherSessions").children().length === 0)
      {
        $("#otherSessionsTitle").text("No other active sessions");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$('.sessionSignOutBtn').submit(function (event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  newAjaxRequest($(this).serialize(), 'index.php?ajax=sessionSignOut', removedSessionBox);
  $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('slow', function ()
  {
    $(this).remove();
    if ($('#otherSessions').is(':empty')) {
      $('#otherSessionsTitle').text('No other active sessions');
    }
  });
});
```